# How to make content of vertical tab hidden by default with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I tried the code of Sergey Romanov about vertical tabs with AngularJS, it works fine, thankx :). But I have a question, I want to specify width of tab's content but when I added to my css file it doesn't work anymore, the content appeared by default. Can you help me?

html file:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row row2" ng-controller="optionsMenu">
            <div class="tabbable"> 
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked nav-pills" role="tablist">
                    <li ng-class="{'active': view_tab == 'tab1'}">
                        <a class="btn-lg" ng-click="changeTab('tab1')" href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li ng-class="{'active': view_tab == 'tab2'}">
                        <a class="btn-lg" ng-click="changeTab('tab2')" href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>


                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane" ng-show="view_tab == 'tab1'">
                                This is tab 1 content
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" ng-show="view_tab == 'tab2'">
                                This is tab 2 content
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css file:

```css
.tabbable{
    position: relative;
    background:rgb(200,200,200);
    padding:0;
    width:50px;
}
.tab-content{
    position:absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    left:100%;
    top:0;
}

.tabbable ul{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%
}
.tabbable ul li{
    border-bottom:1px solid rgb(150,150,150);
}

.row2{
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 350px;
    height: 20%;
    left: 35px;
    top: 60px;
}
```

Thankx for advance

Comment: Could you post some code in a plunkr/fiddle ?

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? This way i am not sure exactly what you want to achieve.

Just to point out, i dont see any usage of `active` class in your stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry for bieng late. I used navbar stacked of bootstrap, I'm just addpted it to my page. After many attempts, I figure out that the solutions is not complicated :), just I need to specify width of tab pane and not tab content.